# Sigsegv / sigabrt when closing the program

Tags: c++, sfml, stdvector, sigabrt, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a sigsegv / sigabrt on my program whenever I close it (sigsev when closing using alt+f4, sigabrt when closing with the window's button [using SFML])

Commenting the call to move(~) will result in a normal exit of the program

```
for(unsigned char i = static_cast<unsigned char>(duckies.size()); i > 0 ; i--){ 
    if(duckies[i].coordinates != duckies[i - 1].coordinates)
        duckies[i].move(duckies[i - 1].direction);
}
```

with duckies being an std::vector of Ducky, and move(~) being

```
void Ducky::move(Direction new_dir){
    direction = new_dir;
    switch(direction){
        case UP:
            --coordinates.y;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            ++coordinates.y;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            --coordinates.x;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            ++coordinates.x;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

(Direction is an enum, Coordinates are 2 int)

Note that this function is called during the program execution, not when it is exiting.

If you have any ideas of what causes that bug, please tell me :).
I may add a link to a github repo if you need it, but I'm not asking you to read all the code, as it's not well documented~

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's your main loop look like?

Comment: Indices are 0-based. This means that `duckies[duckies.size()]` is not a valid index. Accessing it will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoelCornett > Well thanks, it seems it was just that. Any idea why the sig occured only on exit ?

Comment: You'll have to use a debugger to examine what that access is touching in order to gain any insight into that. It could be anything.